# How to use regex to validate a mathematical expression from a string

Tags: python, regex, math

I'm trying to use the eval method in python to evaluate basic mathematical operations written in a string but I check the string first to make sure there isn't nothing wrong going on so I can properly use eval() to evaluate my string.

Here's some of my code right now:

```
import re
s = ("6   + 2 ^ 2")
if re.findall('\d+? *?\+ *?\d+?', s):
    print(eval(s))
else:
    print ("Try entering a math problem")
```

The output is 10, as I wanted.

But when I switch the variable s to equal `"6   + (2 ^  2)"` I get an error message

> "Try entering a math problem"

instead. It still should be 10, but for some reason I am not getting that. For some reason the parentheses mess everything up.

What am I doing wrong in my regex expression?

Comment: Actually `6 + (2 ^ 2)` is `6` in Python.  Try it yourself - just type it into the prompt.  You're confusing `^`, which is bitwise-OR, with `**`, which is exponentiation.  The reason why `6 + 2 ^ 2` is `10` is because it groups as `(6 + 2) ^ 2`, which is `8 ^ 2` which is 10.

Comment: @TomKarzes yea but like how do i still make it so it's 10. cuz like my string now gives me 10, but when I add () it no longer evaluates the string

Comment: oh yea you're right it is

Comment: If you want to change `^` to `**` you can use a regex to make the change.  What you have doesn't work at all.  Try this:  `4 + 2 ^ 2`.  You'll get `4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's useful to write out exactly what you're asserting in your regex. In this case it is:

```py
import re

pat = re.compile('''
\d+?                # one or more digits, taking as few as possible to match
 *?                 # zero or more literal spaces, taking as few as possible to match
\+                  # a literal plus sign
 *?                 # zero or more literal spaces, as before
\d+?                # one or more digits, as before
''', re.X)
```

Unsurprisingly then, you don't handle parentheses anywhere. You could instead do:

```py
import re
pat = re.compile('''
\d+?                # one or more digits, taking as few as possible to match
\s?                 # one or zero space characters
\+                  # a literal plus sign
\s?                 # one or zero space characters
\(?                 # one or zero literal open parentheses
\s?                 # one or zero space characters
\d+?                # one or more digits, as before
''', re.X)
```

However you'll find that no single regex will match all possible mathematical expressions. Mathematical expressions, indeed, are not a regular language, so *regular expressions* are insufficient to parse them. You could look into a syntax parser like `ast`, but the step up in difficulty here is severe.

---

You should also be very aware of the danger of using `eval`. A malicious user could destroy the computer running this code as written, since it will evaluate as python code. Imagine (but *do not attempt*) the following string:

***DO NOT RUN THIS CODE***

`import shutil; 2 + 2; shutil.rmtree("X:\\", ignore_errors=True)`

Since `re.findall` will match against the section `2 + 2`, it evaluates the whole string as python code, which then attempts to delete everything on your X drive. Substitute that for C:\ and you've got a real problem. This is obviously not what you intend.

Comment: @QuoraExpert please see the rest of my answer, but I've edited the regex I posted to handle this single trivial case (previously it expected the number to immediately follow the parenthesis)

Comment: Someone _will_ run that code. How about changing C to R or something else to minimize the damage?

Comment: @DYZ hey why did you make my post a duplicate it's not a duplicate I don't want those answers. I already looked at them bro

Comment: @QuoraExpert yes that's what computers do -- they follow instructions. If you instruct them to delete your hard drive, they'll do that dutifully. Looks like your question very much _is_ a duplicate, and the dupe answer is actually a much better solution than tweaking your regex.

Comment: @AdamSmith that's so many tilnes of code man there has to be a faster way for basic math operators

Comment: @QuoraExpert LOC are cheap, _correctness_ is expensive. Trade the former for the latter any chance you can.